# How can I overload a Scala method by block type?

Tags: scala, dsl

I'm still working on my ScalaTest FeatureSpec DSL.

I'd like 3 variants of my `given` function. All take `tokens: Any`, and then either

A. A block `block: => Unit` that is executed later

```
given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage]) {
    // just code 
}
```

B. A block `block: Any => Unit` that is executed later with the tokens

```
given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage]) { 
  x: Any => x match { 
    case ("user visits", pageClass:Class[Page]) => 
      startPage(pageClass)
  }
}
```

C. No block, where the tokens are processed by another function

```
given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage])
```

Now when I define all three methods

```
def given(tokens: Any) = ...
def given(tokens: Any)(block: Any => Unit) = block(tokens)
def given(tokens: Any)(block: => Unit) = block
```

The compiler considers them ambiguous.

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition, both method given in trait GivenWhenThenFeatureSpec of type (tokens: Any)(block: => Unit)Unit and  method given in trait GivenWhenThenFeatureSpec of type (tokens: Any)(block: (Any) => Unit)Unit match argument types
```

How can disambiguate, or write a single method that can differentiate between the block (or lack of)?

Comment: Do you mean to write `tokens: Any*` or am I missing something?

Comment: Ah yes, or rather no. It is `tokens: Any` and the arguments are packaged up as a tuple that I match on (a-la B above).

Comment: So the final processing of the DSL is a method with a match on the tuple and many cases, fired by the first (non-block) form. The block forms are there to let me prototype the implementations of the cases.

Comment: Is the (C) case one that the tokens are processed immediately or later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like @MachAndy's solution above, except for the importing of the unit2emptyfunction conversions, which I see as possibly interfering or covering other type errors.

If instead you define the following:

```
object Given {
  trait Processor {
    def process(tokens: Any) 
  }
  class ProcessorA(block: =>Unit) extends Processor {
    def process(tokens: Any) = {
      block  // execute or store block for later, ignoring tokens
    }
  }
  class ProcessorB(block: Any=>Unit) extends Processor {
    def process(tokens: Any) = {
      block(tokens) // or store block for later execution
    }
  }
  class ProcessorC extends Processor {
    def process(tokens: Any) = {
      // do something defaultish with the tokens
    }
  }

  implicit def blockToProcessorA(block: =>Unit) = new ProcessorA(block)
  implicit def blockToProcessorB(block: Any=>Unit) = new ProcessorB(block)
  implicit val processorC = new ProcessorC

  def given(tokens: Any)(implicit p: Processor) = p.process(tokens)
}
```

Then, you can simply:

```
import Given._

given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage])
given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage]) {
  // some stuff that ignores tokens
}
given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage]) { x: Any =>
  x match {
    // do something that looks at the tokens
  }
}
```

Comment: This works very well so far, with the small complication that I have had to declare all the blocks as `=> Any` in order to allow the block content to evaluate to something (which is discarded). Thank you.

Comment: Oh and another tiny enhancement was that `implicit object ProcessorC ` allowed me to delete the implicit val.

Comment: **That** was the kind of enhancement I was looking for ! Thank you very much for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have here a solution but I think it can be enhanced.

I used a single `given` method as entry and implicit to provide or not a body

```
def given[A](tokens: A)(implicit block: A => Unit) {
    block(tokens)
}
```

First here is a *sugar* to be able use a  `Unit` block as a `Any => Unit`

```
implicit def unit2emptyfunction(body: Unit): Any => Unit = {
    case _ => body
}
```

To be able to work in the C case, I provide a default body to fill the `block` parameter that does nothing.

```
implicit val doNothing: Any => Unit = { }
```

Now you can use it in this way :

```
/*
 * A case, block is implicitly converted into a A => Unit 
 * although it doesn't use the argument
 */
given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage]) {
    // just code
}


/*
 * B case, block is fully provided and thus not implicitly converted
 */ 
given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage]) {
  case ("user visits", pageClass: Class[Page]) => 
      startPage(pageClass)
}

// C case, block implicitly provided by doNothing implicit val
given("user visits", the[AdminHomePage])
```

Comment: I'm also nervous of the implicits, so am going with Mitch's answer, but thank you for showing that it was possible, as it has let me write some tests knowing that I will be able to parse them.